# Flutter : What is the difference between ! , ? , ?? in Flutter and can someone please explain there use cases

Tags: flutter, dart, null, flutter-test

I wanted to get simplest definition for Null-aware operators in Flutter with their use cases.
and also which one we can use safely as per our use cases.
Please try to explain the key features Null-aware operators in Flutter.

Comment: I suggest you read Dart documentation.

Comment: Try reading this: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Answer (score 2):

`!` is bang operator which is used to cast away nullability.

`?` is used to declare a property nullable.

`??` is used to get the value from a variable if it is non-null or get the other value.

All examples:

```dart
int? i = 42;
print(i!.iEven); // true
int j = i ?? 0; // j = 42
```

Answer (score 1):

`!` use when we are 100 present sure a variable have value.

`?` use when we are not sure our variable have value.

`??` use for conditional situation. For example you have this condition :

```
if(x == null){
  Text('somValue');
}else {
   Text(x);
}
```

we can put it this way:

```
Text(x ?? 'somValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you the difference b/w themby examples.

1. `?` is used when you've a nullable value.
   Ex:

```
List<int>? listOfInt;
```

if I do try to print `list[0]` or `list.first`, it'll give me an error coz the list is nullable and the property after `.` will only work when the list is non-nullable. Hence we've to use `?` like: `list?[0]` or `list?.first` to make sure that it'll proceed further after the `.` if the list is non-nullable.

```
print(listOfInt?.first?.toString());
```

2. `!` is used when the value is defined nullable but you're sure that the value is not null.
   Ex:

```
List<int>? listOfInt = [0, 1];
if(listOfInt == null) print('listOfInt is null');
print(listOfInt!.first.toString());
```

3. `??` is a conditional operator used when the value is null use another value instaed.
   Ex:

```
List<int>? listOfInt = [0, 1];
print(listOfInt?.first?.toString() ?? '0');
```